# Offset of markers and polygon depending on zoom level in Leaflet

Tags: polygon, leaflet, zoom, offset

I have run into a problem with a suspicious offset what comes to self created polygon using Leaflet. I am creating a website using NodeJS (and Pug for rendering the HTML itself). Using Leaflet, I would like to get a polygon drawn on the background map. I am adding the polygon using the old good `var polygon = L.polygon([all coordinates], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map)`. However, the polygon's placement is not accurate. I was at first wondering if it is just some offset since I took coordinates from Google Maps but then I realized, the offset changes depending on the zoom level. I wonder if it is some truncation issue? What can I do here to make it accurate?
I have the same issue with markers. I found multiple threads suggesting that what comes to markers it is the anchors that are not set correctly. I set the anchors on my markers correctly, but the issue still exists. However, the markers I do not care as much for as the polygons. See the picture below for visualization of the offset issue on the polygon upon different zoom levels:
[image]
How can I fix it so that the polygon is accurate, or at the very least always has the same offset regarding the zoom level?

Edit:
A comment mentioned I should include the relevant existing code, here it comes:

Pug:

```
        div#maps
        div.mapcontainer
            div.maptext
                p 2D map
            div#map2d
            script.
                const luleCoords = [65.58438073922254, 22.159403177945457];
                const ltuCoords = [65.61818932415491, 22.140257153674423];
                const fCoords = [65.6194494566347, 22.14276807449434];

                var map2d = L.map('map2d').setView(luleCoords, 12);
                var osm = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
                }).addTo(map2d);

                var bike = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile-cyclosm.openstreetmap.fr/cyclosm/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
                    attribution: '<a href="https://github.com/cyclosm/cyclosm-cartocss-style/releases" title="CyclOSM - Open Bicycle render">CyclOSM</a> | Map data: &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                });

                var esri = L.tileLayer('https://server.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer/tile/{z}/{y}/{x}', {
                    attribution: 'Tiles &copy; Esri &mdash; Source: Esri, i-cubed, USDA, USGS, AEX, GeoEye, Getmapping, Aerogrid, IGN, IGP, UPR-EGP, and the GIS User Community'
                });
                var darkMode = L.tileLayer('https://tiles.stadiamaps.com/tiles/alidade_smooth_dark/{z}/{x}/{y}{r}.png', {
                    attribution: '&copy; <a href="https://stadiamaps.com/">Stadia Maps</a>, &copy; <a href="https://openmaptiles.org/">OpenMapTiles</a> &copy; <a href="http://openstreetmap.org">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                    });

                var ltuLogo = L.icon({
                    iconUrl: '/img/LTU_L_sve_bla.png',
                    iconSize: [50, 50]
                });

                var ltu = L.marker(ltuCoords, {icon: ltuLogo}).addTo(map2d);
                
                var backgrounds = {
                    "Normal": osm,
                    "Dark mode": darkMode,
                    "Bike": bike,
                    "Satelite": esri
                };

                var checkboxes = {
                    "LTU": ltu
                };

                var layerControl = L.control.layers(backgrounds, checkboxes).addTo(map2d);
```

CSS:

```
@media (orientation: landscape) {
.mapcontainer {
    display: inline-block !important;
}

#maps {
    display: flex !important;
    flex-direction: row;
    align-items: center;
}
```

}

```
@media (orientation: portrait) {
    .mapcontainer {
        display: block !important;
    }

    #maps {
        display: flex !important;
        flex-direction: column;
        align-items: center;
    }
}

    .mapcontainer {
    height: 700px;
    text-align: center;
}

.maptext {
    max-height: 50px;
    max-width: 700px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: auto;
    color: navy;
    font-family: Shantell Sans;
}

#map2d {
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    display: block;
    justify-content: center;
}
```

JS:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
const startBtn = document.getElementById('startbtn');
const ltuMarker = document.querySelector('img[alt="Marker"]')

if (startBtn) {
    startBtn.addEventListener('click', () => {
        map2d.setView(fCoords, 17);
    });
}

if (ltuMarker) {

    var fLogo = L.icon({
        iconUrl: '/img/F-Letter-PNG.png',
        iconSize: [100, 100],
        iconAnchor: [50, 50]
    });

    ltuMarker.addEventListener('click', () => {
        map2d.setView(ltuCoords, 16);
        var fHouse = L.marker(fCoords, {icon: fLogo}).addTo(map2d);
        
        layerControl.addOverlay(fHouse, "F house");
        
        var fPolygon = L.polygon([
            [[65.61859390755713, 22.14185649309682], // around
            [65.61906115848446, 22.14480692289698],
            [65.61933952776864, 22.144553224057905],
            [65.61932856696777, 22.144465980084924],
            [65.6193771076222, 22.144416668274108],
            [65.61937084431706, 22.144374942895723],
            [65.61940842412527, 22.14433701073356],
            [65.6193771076222, 22.144143556706513],
            [65.61939902917834, 22.144117004192996],
            [65.61938963422797, 22.144056312733536],
            [65.61943504312323, 22.143976655192986],
            [65.61938806840257, 22.143684577544313],
            [65.6198092720292, 22.143293876274008],
            [65.61993296993765, 22.14405251951732],
            [65.62013182483388, 22.143866651922703],
            [65.61965582317197, 22.140866217895415],
            [65.61944600387915, 22.14105587870624],
            [65.61956187444449, 22.14179555586847],
            [65.61901696512209, 22.142303846841486],
            [65.61889952627037, 22.141567962895476],
            [65.61858948514991, 22.141856247327933]
            ],
            [[65.6189778188972, 22.14272868705774],// hole 1
            [65.6191453643255, 22.143768028301075],
            [65.61927689455851, 22.143646645382148],
            [65.61908116480316, 22.142421436544204],
            [65.61905141375117, 22.142447989057715],
            [65.61907803311509, 22.142633856652328]],
            [[65.61937241014347, 22.143563194625383], // hole 2
            [65.61947105701817, 22.14346836421997],
            [65.61927376289404, 22.14223556894959],
            [65.61917511526985, 22.142330399355004]],
            [[65.61968557353148, 22.143263530544278], // hole 3
            [65.6197826534149, 22.143172493355078],
            [65.61968557353148, 22.142561785544213],
            [65.61958849328514, 22.142649029517194]],
            [[65.61956657188895, 22.14250868051718], // hole 4
            [65.61966365221727, 22.142421436544204],
            [65.61958536165822, 22.1419396980847],
            [65.61948984685658, 22.14203073527389]],
        ], {color: 'red'}).addTo(map2d);
    });        
}
```

});

Comment: Coding question on GIS SE site should include relevant existing code, otherwise it's most likely to be closed as not compliant with the site policy. Please edit your question and add relevant existing code. Add also an image and coordinates of wrongly placed marker. Polygon GeoJSON would help also.

Comment: The attribution control is out of its place, so I'm gonna guess this is a CSS offset gone awry.

Comment: Thank you for the replies. @TomazicM I have now added the relevant code. Sorry for how chaotic it is.

Comment: @IvanSanchez This is an interesting observation. Not only that, but also the zoom in buttons seem to be a bit too deep in. Any ideas where to look further/what to do about it? I do not have any padding or margins in there so I am feeling very clueless.

Comment: The usual: use your web browser's debugging tools to inspect the CSS rules being applied to DOM elements created by Leaflet.

Answer (score 3):

This is not really an answer, it's just that comments with pictures are not possible.

I could not replicate described behavior in plain JS Leaflet. This is the map I got:

[image]

There is still some offset, but display of polygon is correct. For example, this is how the upper left corner coordinate is shown on epsg.io site(https://epsg.io/map#srs=4326&x=22.140866&y=65.619655&z=19&layer=streets):

[image]

This corresponds with upper left corner on Leaflet map.

Comment: Such a small offset feels very reasonable, it could very well be an error in the coordinates as they are not ultra precise. I think Ivan was on the right track, since the attribution as well as layers and zoom controls seem to be in the right spots for you but not for me.

Answer (score 1):

Found the issue. It was indeed in CSS. I had a margin 10 on all divs. Yepp, never hit me that it would influence the map as well.
Thanks for all the help.